# rubberband selection in 3d webgl-three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Iam trying to do rubberband selection.

1. I draw a rectangle div in 2d.
2. Then i convert the 2d to 3d with three.js (intersection technique).

now my Questions are -

1. how to find the elements/faces that were inside the rectangle div.
2. Is there any other way to draw rubber band in 3d.

Can anyone give me your valuable guidance on doing rubberband-selection technique in 3d(webgl-three.js).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean a lasso selection?

Comment: yes like lasso selection, in rectangle

Comment: iam trying for rectangle marquee tool selection

Comment: wow!! finally i complete this rubberband selection. three.js have great math work in it. Thanks all.

Comment: @user2089677 Is this work public or open source? Am trying to create something very similar 

Comment: Can you share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the three.js source code that seems to be doing what you described:

https://threejs.org/examples/misc_boxselection.html